# Android Kotlin Recylverview not working after androidx upgrade

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I recently updated my support designs to AndroidX using  Refactor... and now my recyclerview just doesn't work anymore:

```
class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CommentGrabber.CommentGrabberResponse {
private var commentsList: ArrayList<Comment> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var commentGrabber: CommentGrabber
private val groupAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
private lateinit var groupLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_full)

    commentGrabber = CommentGrabber(this)
    populateAdapter()

    groupLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, groupAdapter.spanCount).apply {
        spanSizeLookup = groupAdapter.spanSizeLookup
    }

    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = groupLayoutManager
        adapter = groupAdapter
    }

}
```

I keep getting the error that groupLayoutManager should be an integer and that "adapter" is not found at all.

Someone please help!

Comment: Can you please add error screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added this as below

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

Replace recyclerView in `.xml`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
...
/>
```

also make sure from your adapter side and another place you are widgets of `androidx` 
and also you are importing `androidx`  gradel like below.

```
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
  import androidx...
```

Comment: Yes! It was the recyclerview in the layout! Forgot to change THAT to androidx. Thanks!